# Log a mongoose db entry using winston - node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, winston

I have a schema:

```
var nameSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  surname: String,
  word: String
})
var nameSchema = mongoose.model('nameSchema', nameSchema)
```

Which updates my dbs fields every time I run my code. This is what my dbs entry looks like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"), "name" : "Tom", "surname" : "Qwerty", "word" : "secret", "__v" : 0 }
```

Now once this dbs entry is saved successfully, I want to make a winston log too, passing this dbs information to the log. So it will look something like this:

```
 var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.File)({
        filename: './logs/example.log',
        level: 'info',
        timestamp: true,
        event: 'MY DBS ENTRY'   
      })
    ]
  });
```

My thinking is around these line...

```
logger.log('info', "db.?? -NOT SURE");
```

So the log file would look like this:

```
{"level":"info","event":"{"name" : "Tom", "surname" : "Qwerty", "word" : "secret"}","timestamp":"2016-08-11T10:44:49.527Z"}
```

Any help or tips appreciated

Comment: How are you inserting or updating your DB? can you post some cde?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are inserting in your DB. While saving the document, you will have access to currently saved document. Thus, in the call back you can use that document to create your `winston log`.

```
var user = new nameSchema();
user.name = "tom";
user.surname = "Qwerty";
user.word = "secret";

user.save(function(err,user)
{
    if(!err)
    {
        //use the currently inserted document and log it in your logger.
        logger.log('info',user);
        // OR:
        // if you just want specific information to log in logger, cerate another variable for it.
        var temp = {};
        temp.name= user.name;
        temp.surname = user.surname;
        temp.word = user.word; 
        logger.log('info',temp);
    }

});
```

Comment: Hmm good idea, I assume this would work with findOneAndUpdate too?